# MediaPlayer stopped working randomly

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I was making an app that will play different sounds when a function is called:

```
public void playAudio(int id){
    mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), id);
    mPlayer.start();
}
```

The function is called like this:

```
playAudio(R.raw.sound)
```

(this audio is in MP3 format)

When I ran this (without the function, just directly where needed), it worked fine, after using it a little, it stopped working and sent the following error:

```
D/AudioSystem: getIoDescriptor: ioHandle = 13, index = -2, mIoDescriptors = 0x748a1e6950
D/AudioSystem: getIoDescriptor: ioHandle = 21, index = -2, mIoDescriptors = 0x748a1e6950
D/AudioSystem: getIoDescriptor: ioHandle = 29, index = -2, mIoDescriptors = 0x748a1e6950
           getIoDescriptor: ioHandle = 93, index = -2, mIoDescriptors = 0x748a1e6950
D/AudioSystem: getIoDescriptor: ioHandle = 101, index = -2, mIoDescriptors = 0x748a1e6950
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
D/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
E/ExtMediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer could not be located....
D/MediaPlayer-JNI: JNIMediaPlayerFactory: bIsQCMediaPlayerPresent 0
I/MediaPlayer: constructor
I/MediaPlayer: setListener
D/MediaPlayer-JNI: MediaExPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
I/MediaPlayer: MediaPlayer::setAudioSessionId(7369)
I/MediaPlayer: setDataSource(69, 6395068, 35730)
```

This error doesn't crash the program, just doesn't play any audio. I also tried SoundPool with Samsung's documentation: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy/others/playing-audio-and-video-in-android
I've also read other StackOverflow questions, still, no solution. And please, before you answer, understand that this **did** work, it just randomly stopped after using the app a couple of times.

Thanks in advance,
Jack

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133314/qcmediaplayer-could-not-be-located-on-xamarin-android. Did you found a workaround in between?